# importing categories and sub categories from CSV to woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I have a CSV with products and categories that I am importing into woo-commerce.

I would like to import the sub-categories as well.

The categories column displays the categories as:

EMC,Power Amplifier,Accessories.

i.e (EMC)main category, (Power Amplifier)subcategory, (Accessories)subcategory.

It does import the categories, but not in a hierarchy structure  - It just imports them all as categories. Is there anyway to do achieve this with the CSV import into woo-commerce, where you can import the subcategories as well?

Any Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For hierarchy, you need to use >

Example

EMC > Power Amplifier > Accessories